# How to disable to move TeeChart in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, teechart

I'm in trouble: I have Xamarin.Android application using TeeChart in it. After creating chart and displaing data on it, I can click on chart and drag to any place on application. May be anybody knows how to disable to move TeeChart?

```
var tChart1 = new TChart(this);
            tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
            tChart1.Aspect.View3D = !tChart1.Aspect.View3D;
            tChart1.Header.Text = String.Empty;
            tChart1.Clickable = false;
            tChart1.Enabled = false;
            tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.ValueFormat = "###.0";
            tChart1.Clickable = false;
            tChart1.Axes.Left.Visible = true;
            tChart1.Axes.Left.LabelsOnAxis = true;
            tChart1.Axes.Top.Visible = false;
            tChart1.Axes.Right.Visible = false;
            tChart1.Axes.Right.LabelsOnAxis = true;
            tChart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelsOnAxis = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TeeChart for Xamarin.Android you can disable zooming and panning setting *Zoom.Style* to *ZoomStyles.Classic* and some zoom and Panning settings as shown here:

```
  tChart1.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.Classic;
  tChart1.Zoom.Allow = false;
  tChart1.Panning.Allow = Steema.TeeChart.ScrollModes.None;
```

Please bear in mind this functionality is only available from [4.14.6.25 version](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=15018) published a few weeks ago. So if you are using an older version, please update it to the latest to be able to use this functionality.